# INNER JOIN com um SELECT TOP

Tags: sql-server, select, inner

Ao gerar um script, tentei modificar um **where** para **inner join**. No entanto, o tempo ao rodar com inner join foi mais de 10 minutos e com o where, foi em questão de segundos, conforme o exemplo abaixo. Gostaria de saber porque essa diferença de performance.

Obs: Inseri apenas o começo do script.

```
SELECT
   cs.sym as 'Status',
   crt.sym as 'Tipo',
   ccc.last_name as 'Contato',
   co.abbreviation as 'Lotação do contato',

   ISNULL((SELECT TOP 1
                    cc.last_name
             FROM
                    act_log al WITH (NOLOCK), ca_contact cc WITH (NOLOCK)
             WHERE
                    cr.persid = al.call_req_id
                    AND al.analyst = cc.contact_uuid
                    AND al.type = 'cl'
             ORDER BY al.id DESC),'') as 'Fechada por',

             --OU--

    ISNULL((SELECT TOP 1
                    cc.last_name

             FROM call_req as cr

               inner join act_log as al on (cr.persid = al.call_req_id)
               inner join ca_contact as cc on (al.analyst = cc.contact_uuid)

             WHERE al.type = 'soln'

             ORDER BY al.id DESC),'') as 'Fechada por',
```

Comment: a diferença nao parece ser só o inner join ou where... tire o top 1 e execute o select isolado para ver a diferença dos resultados

Comment: As queries não são "bem" iguais. Na primeira você está lendo dados não *commited*  usando `WITH (NOLOCK)`, você deveria por isso na segunda query (`inner join act_log as al WITH (NOLOCK)`). Segundo o `WHERE` também é diferente no campo `al.type`. Tente deixar as duas queries iguais e execute novamente. O *execution plan* pode ajudar a identificar diferenças também

Comment: O código está incompleto e não permite análise correta. Entretanto, observa-se que os dois trechos são construções diferentes e não podem ser comparados diretamente. No segundo trecho há 3 tabelas na cláusula FROM; já no primeiro trecho há 2 tabelas na cláusula FROM e provavelmente  é uma subconsulta correlacionada, por causa de `cr.persid = al.call_req_id`. Além disso, o filtro para a coluna `al.type` é diferente nos dois trechos.